# How to send data from Main Activity to BroadcastReceiver?

Tags: android

I know that exists thread about that, but I can't get how to do it, I only need send data a Broadcast, this is the code

**Main activity**

```
 public void passData(){
    passIntent = new Intent(this,Notification_Reciever.class);
    path=String.valueOf(recibidor_file.get(recibidor_position).getAbsolutePath());
    passIntent.putExtra("KEY",path);
    sendBroadcast(passIntent);

}
```

**BroadCast**

```
public class Notification_Reciever extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    String action=intent.getAction();
    String value=intent.getStringExtra("KEY");
    if(Constantes.ACTION.PLAY_ACTION.equals(action)){
        actionPlay();
        Toast.makeText(context,""+value,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    if(Constantes.ACTION.PREV_ACTION.equals(action)){

    }

    if(Constantes.ACTION.NEXT_ACTION.equals(action)){

    }
}
```

**Manifest**

```
<receiver android:name=".Notification_Reciever">

        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true">

        <intent-filter>

            <action android:name="PLAY_ACTION"/>

        </intent-filter>

    </receiver>
```

Always get null

Comment: Are you getting String value=intent.getStringExtra("KEY"); as null?  Can you check what do you get value of path after path=String.valueOf(recibidor_file.get(recibidor_position).getAbsolutePath()); line

Comment: Yeah "(recibidor_file.get(recibidor_position).g‌​etAbsolutePath()" is a music file inside of ArrayList(recibidor_file), in the MainActivity works but in the broadcast only get null

Comment: @FelipePeña set action for the intent which will be same as the action provided in manifest for the receiver.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have intent-filter defined in manifest,

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="PLAY_ACTION"/>
</intent-filter>
```

You need to set action to your intent in order to receive data...

```
passIntent = new Intent(this,Notification_Reciever.class);
passIntent.setAction("PLAY_ACTION");
path = String.valueOf(recibidor_file.get(recibidor_position).getAbsolutePath());
passIntent.putExtra("KEY",path);
sendBroadcast(passIntent);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have no set an action to the intent which you are broadcasting.

`passIntent = new Intent("action");`

In your case 'passIntent = new Intent(Constantes.ACTION.PREV_ACTION);` or whichever the action that you want to broadcast.

You can also use `intent.setAction(action)` to set an action.

Comment: No, these actions are for a service apart, I only want send data I read here and many page used intent but I don't know how apply

Comment: The action is applicable for Broadcast as well. I explained the same point of the accepted answer. May be I wasn't as clear as that answer.

Comment: I am sorry, English is not my first language, I undertand better with examples very very detailed

Answer (score 0):

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction("com.example.Broadcast");
intent.putExtra("data", "data");
sendBroadcast(intent);
```

> your manifest file should have something like this ..

```
<receiver android:name="MyReceiver" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.example.Broadcast" >
                </action>
        </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

> You have to register your broadcast receiver in your activity..

```
IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter("com.example.Broadcast");

MyReceiver receiver = new MyReceiver();
registerReceiver(receiver, filter);
```

> And your broadcast receiver will be like this

```
public class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
         // Implement code here to be performed when 
            // broadcast is detected
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to set action here.In manifest it is already registered

```
 public void passData(){
    passIntent = new Intent(this,Notification_Reciever.class);
    passIntent.setAction("PLAY_ACTION");  path=String.valueOf(recibidor_file.get(recibidor_position).getAbsolutePath();passIntent.putExtra("KEY",path);
    sendBroadcast(passIntent);
    }
```

Comment: Happy coding !!

Comment: LOL its funny :) !!

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of broadcast. do it like this

```
Intent intent = new Intent("IncomingChat");
                intent.putExtra("visitor",    String.valueOf(eventParameters[0]));
                intent.putExtra("Action", "receivedincommingchats");
                LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context).sendBroadcast(intent);
```

and add this to the activity where you want to receive the broadcast

```
   @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getActivity()).registerReceiver(IncomingBroadcastReceiver, new IntentFilter("IncomingChat"));
        }


private final BroadcastReceiver IncomingBroadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

            String Action = intent.getStringExtra("Action");
            switch (Action){
                case "receivedincommingchats":
                    String recVisit = intent.getStringExtra("visitor");

                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
    };
```